# On the number of faces of dual graph

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, planar-graphs

Let $G$ be a planar, connected graph with $n$ vertices, $m$ edges and $\Phi$ sides. Prove that in his dual graph $G^\ast$ the number of sides is $\Phi(G^\ast)=n$. Sorry for my English, thanks!

Comment: @PrudiiArca *face* is more common

Comment: @PaulHudford right. The common terminology for *side* is *face*

Comment: @PaulHudford is this question on the planar dual or the abstract dual graph?

Comment: That's the exact same question. Voting to close for duplicate